# Set to Boolean value based on IN clause

Tags: mysql

How can the following be performed in a single query?

```
UPDATE clients SET online=0 WHERE id NOT IN(4,5,8,10,12) AND id>=2 AND id<=15 AND parentId=123;
UPDATE clients SET online=1 WHERE id     IN(4,5,8,10,12) AND id>=2 AND id<=15 AND parentId=123;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`CASE .. WHEN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) statement:

```
UPDATE clients 
SET online = CASE WHEN id IN(4,5,8,10,12)
                    THEN 1 
                  ELSE 0 
             END
WHERE
    id BETWEEN 2 AND 15 AND parentId = 123;
```

---

[`IN(..)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) is a Logical/Comparison function. So you can do the following (**in MySQL only**) as well:

```
UPDATE clients 
    SET online = (id IN(4,5,8,10,12)) 
    WHERE
        id BETWEEN 2 AND 15 AND parentId = 123;
```

Comment: Ah, CASE!  Didn't think of that.

Comment: @user1032531 check the updated answer for one more possibility

Comment: Please note that boolean expressions returning 0 or 1 is a MySQL feature that doesn't normally work in other DBMS. `CASE ... END` is of course pretty portable.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález thanks. added MySQL only Caveat for other solution